# Using Python for JSON calls

Tags: python, json

Here is the class I'm trying to use

```
class Products(Resource):
    """The collection of products in a store"""

    def get(self):
        """Returns list of products"""
        products_list = self.client.request_json('GET', '/products?limit=%s&page=%s' % (self.paginate_by, self.current_page))
        return [Product(product) for product in products_list]
```

Here is my script:

```
import bigcommerce.api

bigcommerce.api.Connection.host = 'https://store-qvek.mybigcommerce.com'
bigcommerce.api.Connection.user = 'admin'
bigcommerce.api.Connection.api_key = '272956b18e3a7c269b413385908cc7371f5c41'


products_list = bigcommerce.api.Products.get()
for product in products_list:
    print product.name
```

I'm missing something in the Products.get()....but what?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wget\bin\test_bigcommerce.py", line 8, in <module>
    products_list = bigcommerce.api.Products.get()
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with Products instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

P.S The code will not work since I've changed the host and api key in order to post it public.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What are the expected and actual outcomes?

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of my products using Python....when I run my code i get the following error....Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wget\bin\test_bigcommerce.py", line 8, in <module>
    products_list = bigcommerce.api.Products.get()
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with Products instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: The problem is obviously in the `bigcommerce` module or how you use it. You should review the documentation and/or ask in a more specific forum. Without more information it is impossible you get an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is little documentation for the bigcommerce python api....i'm still fairly new to python and really new to calling websites with JSON...how does this "('GET', '/products?limit=%s&page=%s' % (self.paginate_by, self.current_page))" translate into the .get() call?

Comment: @user2152584: The `string % tuple` is a Python format operator. The result is another string where '%s' is replaced with the values of the tuples. That string is likely used directly as the url to get.

Comment: OK cool, I'm starting to get it...now how would i translate it....this URL works within a brower '/products?limit=200&page=1' and it returns all my products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class `Products` but never create an instance of that.

Create an instance instead:

```
bigcommerce.api.Products().get()
```